# Error while installing chatterbot library through command prompt

Tags: python, chatterbot

I've been trying to install the chatterbot library. I've tried by using pip install and downloading from git but its giving me an error that I cant resolve.
ERROR: Package 'chatterbot' requires a different Python: 3.9.1 not in '<=3.8,>=3.4'

Comment: ...because it requires python 3.4-3.8 and 3.9 isn't one of those versions? Just downgrade to 3.8 until 3.9 is supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, you will need a new environment with python 3.6

You can change the name "example",put your favorite name.

conda create -n example python=3.6

Every time that you work with your chatbot you will need enter in this environment:

conda activate example

Please if you have more question let me know.

After this maybe you will need spaCy library --> https://spacy.io

Answer (score -1):

try installing Chatterbot v1.0.2

pip install chatterbot==1.0.2

or download a python version  3.4 to 3.8

Comment: I've downloaded chatterbot v1.0.2 but when I try to run a program on jupyter it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot'

Comment: try to use python 3.8